# What do I need to connect an R-SMA male to a standard coaxial male?

Tags: antenna, adapter, reverse-polarity, coax, coaxial

I have a router that has the following type of pigtail connector soldered to the board which I believe is an R-SMA male coaxial cable.

[image: R SMA Male]

I'd like to connect it to a standard male coaxial cable that's connected to an antenna outside my house to broadcast a wireless signal from the router. The cable connected to said antenna looks like this:

[image: Male Coaxial Cable]

I believe this is a standard male coaxial cable.

Do you have suggestions, links, or feedback on what I need to purchase to connect these two such that I can get a longer range of broadcast from my router?

Comment: By "standard coaxial cable" do you mean it's an F connector? If so, you're going to need more than just a converter; F connectors are universally used for 75 Ω cable, and your standard router is going to use 50 Ω. You'll need some kind of impedance matching network.

Comment: I can’t say I’ve ever seen an adapter that will do that in one step, so perhaps you’ll need a short length of coax with the appropriate connectors.  Be aware that the attenuation at 2.4GHz is quite high in ‘typical’ coax so keep the length as short as possible and check the specification of the cable you intend to use - you should be able to find attenuation per metre at different frequencies.

Comment: R-SMA **is** a standard - you're looking for an adapter to connect one standard connector to a different one, basically.

Comment: I suppose the question is really about whether this antenna is compatible with this router. You can't just hook any antenna to anything and expect it to work, since antenna designs are frequency-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect an RP-SMA connector to an F connector, of course you need an appropriate RP-SMA-to-F-connector adapter (pay attention to male and female - I always get them mixed up with coax connectors).

However, this might not actually help you. Both antennas and coax cables are designed for certain frequency bands and have characteristic impedances; antennas also have radiation patterns. Connecting your home's TV antenna to your wi-fi router won't extend your wi-fi range because this adapter is poorly suited for this frequency. In addition, the antenna is designed to beam the signal at the nearby TV transmitter, where it is pointed, not at your laptop. There is a small chance of damaging the router as the signal will be reflected - though if it's not damaged with no antenna plugged in, it probably won't be damaged by the wrong antenna, either.